# MVC: Refreshing a grid via jQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a grid (foreach in view) which is shown based on a GET request.

For the POST request, I want to return a filtered view of the grid. The grid is already a partial view, so just returning the grid is no problem.

However, I am looking for some sample code on how I get my filter conditions (there are quite a few, I would have those selected clientside via dropdowns) back to the controller's POST request.

I'd really appreciate some sample code, client & server side **using jQuery** as the Javascript library for the client side code.

Thank you!

Comment: Alex, did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I figured it out myself (the top answer was helpful, but not completely what I was looking for because I missed the C# side which I understood by now.. not that hard.) You basically define a field such as <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"/> and when you place this within a form which you then post to a controller, you can catch the input on the controller side via the controller method: public ActionResult MyControllerMethod(String firstname). The "firstname" method param of the controller method you are posting to will be filled with the value of the identically named input.

Answer (score 2):

I write code like this.

```
var url = '<%= Url.Action("List", new { controller = "ControllerName" }) %>';
$.post(url,
    $("#criteria_form").serialize(),
    function(data) {
      $("#list_holder").html(data);
    }
);
```

Comment: Could you please explain your code a bit more detailed, and also show the C# side? Thank you!

Comment: There is nothing more really. The C# just renders a View which is a user control and it gets returned as the data parameter. The criteria are passed as parameters to the action.

Comment: How do you deserialize the data parameters in the action?

Meaning, how does the signature look like: public ActionResult Filter(?????) and how do you access the individual serialized items from the criteria_form?

Comment: They will be deserialized automagically. So if you have a criteria field called SearchText then have a parameter SearchText and it will pick it up.

Comment: I still dont see it. Please tell me how I will bring the content of the field SearchText into a string inside of my controller method.

String searchText = ???

Comment: When you call the $("#").serialize() it will create the data to be passed to the controller which is then mapped to the Action parameters. How does it work? It doesn't really matter as it is all handled by MVC framework. Quote:"The ASP.NET MVC framework can automatically map URL parameter values to parameter values for action methods. By default, if an action method takes a parameter, the MVC framework examines incoming request data and determines whether the request contains an HTTP request value with the same name. If so, the request value is automatically passed to the action method"

Answer (score 1):

The C# part would look like this, if you use Craig's example, note that the action's  arguments need to have the same name as in the html search criteria form !

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(string searchtext)
{
     // retrieve data here based on searchtext


     //return partial view to be used in the grid
     return View("_partial", myDataCollection)
}
```

You can also look into jQuery addons like jqGrid or [TableSorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).

Comment: Thanks for the links, jqGrid looks just like what I have been looking for!